# Response of a system using DFT

Tags: dft, convolution

Let's say that we have two sequences, input sequence $x(n) = [0121]$ and impulse response of a given system $h(n) = [0, 1, -1, 1]$. I need to find response of this system to given input sequence. After that, i need to calculate linear convolution of given sequences.

If we denote the response as $y(n)$ we have $y(n)=h(n)*x(n)$, which means that, due to convolution theorem, in frequency domain we have $Y(k)=H(k)X(k)$. From this, we can find $y(n) = IDFT(Y(k))$.

Considering the fact that i need to find convolution of given sequences, meaning $y(n)=h(n)*x(n)$, that would mean that it should yield same result as when i was doing this by using DFT. However, my final results don't match at all.

$x(n) = [0121] \Rightarrow X(k) = [4, -2, 0, -2] \\ h(n) = [0, 1, -1, 1] \Rightarrow H(k) = [1, 1, -3, 1] \\ Y(k)=X(k)H(k) = [4, -2, 0, -2] \Rightarrow y(n)=[0, 1, 2, 1]$

On the other hand, convolution of given sequences gives the following result:

$y(n) = h(n)*x(n) = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]$

Not only that result is completely wrong, but also dimensions of vectors i got as a result are not the same. What am i doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to do _zero-padding_ before computing the DFTs in order to use the DFTs to calculate the _linear_ convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will match for circular convolution modulo $N$, where $N$ is 4 here. For finite length sequences product of DFT of 2 sequences is equivalent to DFT of circular-convolution of the 2 sequences.

```
>> cconv([0,1,2,1], [0,1,-1,1], 4)

ans =

 0     1     2     1
```

---

```
>>ifft(fft([0,1,2,1]).*fft([0,1,-1,1]))

ans =

 0     1     2     1
```